# What does ln stand for?

Tags: symlink, ln

In Linux you can use the `ln` command to make links.

```
$ touch foo
$ ln -s foo foo_link
$ ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx  1 cklein cklein         3 May 29 16:11 foo_link -> foo
```

I assume that the 'l' in `ln` stands for "link", but what does the 'n' stand for?

What does `ln` stand for?

Answer (score 44):

All the `ln` means "link", not just the "l".
Just the same as `ls` meaning "list", `cp` means "copy" and `mv` means "move".

They are part of the "two letter commands", for example:

- `ar` — ARchive
- `as` — ASsembler
- `bc` — Basic Calculator
- `cc` — C Compiler
- `cp` — CoPy files and directories
- `dc` — Desk Calculator
- `dd` — Data Description: convert and copy a file
- `df` — Disk Free: report file system disk space usage
- `du` — Disk Usage
- `ed` — EDitor
- `ld` — Link eDitor
- `ln` — make LiNks between files
- `lp` — Line Printer
- `ls` — LiSt directory contents
- `mv` — MoVe (rename) files
- `nl` — Number Lines of file
- `nm` — NaMe list
- `od` — Octal Dump
- `pg` — PaGinate
- `pr` — (PRetty) PRint
- `ps` — Process Status: report a snapshot of the current proceses.
- `rm` — ReMove files or directories
- `sh` — SHell
- `su` — run a command with Substitute User and group ID / originally Super User
- `vi` — VIsual editor
- `wc` — Word Count

Comment: I think that `su` comes from 'super user' instead

Comment: Maybe, or just "switch user".

Comment: Actually, checking in the UNIX PROGRAMMER’S MANUAL, Seventh Edition, Volume 1, January, 1979. It says 'substitute user'.

Comment: @FrederikDeweerdt Thanks for the clarification. It's good to know those details.

Comment: I think your description for `su` is a bit misleading. `su` runs a command with a substitute user and group ID. It doesn't change the current user's UID or make the current user a superuser.

Comment: @EvanTeitelman I disagree. I took that description of `su` from `man su`. My manual was written on 2011-02-16 (may be not the last update --I'm using Gentoo Linux--, but definitely the `su` manual itself.)

Comment: util-linux added a manpage for `su` in May of 2012 based on the GNU coreutil 'su invocation' info page. It is possible that the manpage you are looking at was created by a third party (i.e. somebody other than a util-linux or GNU developer). Third party manpages are not always subject to the sort of careful inspection that project-provided manpages are subject to. That may explain why the manpage you are looking contains a potentially-misleading description.

Comment: @EvanTeitelman It's possible. I'm updating the answer using the definition in [GNU Coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/su-invocation.html). Thanks.

Comment: Besides that, your answer is excellent, so here's a +1 from me.

Comment: The [Unix First Edition man pages](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-1st/1/) are available on the Internet.

Comment: "Switch/substitute user" may be more accurate now, but historically, the oldest available implementation of `su`, in Unix v5 (1974), could only switch to super-user: http://pthree.org/2009/12/31/the-meaning-of-su/

Comment: Read somewhere `ls` is an acronym for List Segments... archaic clearly jlwallen https://www.brighthub.com/computing/linux/articles/14459.aspx

I get a feeling you made a lot of these up lol. Also,

 "grep" is an acronym for Global Regular Expression Print